# How to: Eclipse RAP configuration external ip, listen 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I have a RAP application that is running on a certain port (8181). I can access my application from local ip: 192.168.0.230 but I can't access my application from my provider's link.

My router port is forwarded...

How can I configure my RAP application to listen to 0.0.0.0 interface?

P.S: I am sure that there is no problem in the router

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can configure in RAP, but in your servlet container. The servlet container is the one that opens network sockets. The default configuration is usually to listen to all interfaces.

Besides, if you can access your application over an 192.168.* ip, this means that your servlet container actually listens to this interface, otherwise you could only access it on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). So it seems to be a networking problem.

Comment: I will check that again. Thank you!